# Oracle Apex IG column refresh after submit based on PLSQL

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a Interactive Grid with few columns and one dummy 'Status' column. The status column will be blank initially. I am populating the IG records in a Apex collection and then pass those in a PLSQL package.
My requirement is to refresh the IG region after the package execution is completed and show the IG status column as success/failed based on PLSQL package outcome.

Please suggest if this is doable.

Comment: Please explain the business flow in more detail. User opens the page... then what happens ? The pl/sql package you mention - when and how does that get invoked ? is this an editable IG ?

Comment: Business flow is as below -
1. User run the IG report based on a SQL query, it has a status column with NULL values.
2. User selects few rows and save the records for processing.
3. Dynamic action and Page process process those records in database.

Requirement is to populate the status column with success/error after the page process is completed.

Answer (score 0):

> I am populating the IG records in a Apex collection and then pass those in a PLSQL package

If you do that in a **process** which fires when you **Submit** the page, then this

> refresh the IG region after the package execution is completed

will  *automatically* happen.

Comment: The requirement is to refresh the status column.

Answer (score 0):

@Littlefoot is correct.
Let's look at your updated requirements:

*3. Dynamic action and Page process process those records in database.*
Well... at that point you probably need to update the processed rows with the status (in the collection), or store the status in another table you can join to so it is shown in the IG. You state "after the page process". That means that the page is submitted so the page will refresh anyway and the IG should show the new values, including the updated status.